# jQuery Pagination like AuthenticJobs.com

Tags: jquery, pagination

What plugin does that?

http://www.authenticjobs.com/

Check out the job listing pagination (Load next 50 jobs).

I know I've seen a plugin for this, but I can't remember it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need a plugin for this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ButtonToClickToLoadNext50").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getjobs",
            data: {
                start: 51,
                end: 100
            },
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, status, xhttp)
            {
                var html = "";

                for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
                {
                    // build up html
                    html += "<div>content to display</div>";
                }

                $("#divcontainingjobs").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```